# Unix/OSX/Git - Is there a way to select a file or branch returned by git status/branch without highlighting it w/ the cursor?

Tags: macos, git, unix, command-line

Let's say I run

```
git status
```

and see a list of modified files. How can I select one of them without typing the full file name or highlighting the file name with my cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with the command line tools and you are using bash, you can use the auto-completion script shipped with Git.  Details are [in the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion).

These tools will let you use your `tab` key to autocomplete filenames, branch names, tags, etc.